# $\left[LF:K\right]\leq\left[L:K\right]\left[F:K\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L,F$ be extensions over the field $K$ and $L,F$ are contained in a common field. Prove that $\left[LF:K\right]\leq\left[L:K\right]\left[F:K\right]$

If $L,F$ are finite extensions over $K$, I'm done. How do I prove for the case infinite extension?

Thank in advanced.

Comment: @GerryMyerson He said he has problems with the infinite case, not the whole thing. However, I think he is done already, because, if either $[L:K]$ or $[F:K]$ were infinite, then we interpret $[L:K] [F:K] = \infty$ and then the inequality is clearly true.

Comment: Ehm, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural morphism of $K$-algebras$$L\otimes_K F \to LF:l\otimes f\mapsto l\cdot f$$  is surjective, so that $[L\otimes_K F:K]\geq [LF:K]$.
On the other hand  $[L\otimes_K F:K]) =[L:K] \cdot [F:K]$, hence we immediately get the required inequality between cardinals $$ [L:K] \cdot [F:K]\geq\left[LF:K\right] $$ without any finiteness hypothesis.

Note carefully that the interpretation above of $[-:-]$  as a cardinal number  yields a more precise result than the convention of attributing $\infty$ as the dimension of any infinite field extension.

Comment: I haven't study $K$ -algebras already. Can you explain with a different esier way?

Comment: Dear @chuyenvien94, I agree that my answer is a bit sophisticated but I thought the result and the method of proof might interest more advanced users. I'm sure the many excellent algebraists on this site will give excellent answers of a more elementary nature.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Dear chuyenvien94, you are welcome.

Comment: The answer does not help the user who asks and does not offer additional help.